# Source for WinJS.UI.Menu and WinJS.UI.MenuCommand

Tags: windows-8, menu, winjs

For some reason, I was under the impression that the source code for WinJS.UI.Menu and WinJS.UI.MenuCommand will be in ui.js file that get added under References -> Windows Library for JavaScript 1.0 but its not there. Any suggestion as to where can I find its source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is in UI.js only. I can see it around line # 35016

```
WinJS.Namespace.define("WinJS.UI", {
    Menu: WinJS.Class.derive(WinJS.UI
```